# How to disable several date using isInvalidDate in date range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, date

I want disable several date in date range picker.

I can disable from 10 Oct 2017 - 15 Oct 2017, as follows :

```
var cekA = document.getElementById('HF_StartDateBlockMasterPage').value;
var cekB = document.getElementById('HF_EndDateBlockMasterPage').value;

$('#daterange').daterangepicker({
    isInvalidDate: function (date) {
        var formatted = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        if (date >= moment(cekA) && date <= moment(cekB)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

and that code working fine.

But what if I want disable from 10 Oct 2017 to 15 Oct 2017 and again 25 Oct 2017 to 30 Oct 2017?
[example my html](https://codepen.io/travsys/pen/LjvPEW)

Comment: I dont understand your question from "but how if i want disable date from 10 Oct 2017 until 15 Oct 2017 and disable again 25 Oct 2017 until 30 Oct 2017." Would you be more clear about that? [travsyst travsyst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8560561/travsyst-travsyst)

Comment: i'm sory. i want disable two date. disable one. disable date from from 10 Oct 2017 until 15 Oct 2017  and disable two 25 Oct 2017 until 30 Oct 2017, so i in October i have available date 21 Oct until 24 Oct 2017..

Comment: Can you post the HTML which you have implemented so far? Or any JSFiddle?

Comment: You just need to add further `if (date >= moment(foo) && date <= moment(bar)) { return true; }` condition(s) to the `isInvalidDate` callback, each condition representing a block of dates to be disabled.

Comment: @ Phani Kumar M , please cek in top..

Comment: this is..https://codepen.io/travsys/pen/LjvPEW

Comment: @travsysttravsyst Please check the comment from Roamer-1888 above. The solution is already provided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to add further condition(s) to the isInvalidDate callback, each condition representing a date or block of dates to be disabled.

For example, you could write :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var a = moment("2017-10-10");
    var b = moment("2017-10-15");
    var x = moment("2017-10-25");
    var y = moment("2017-10-30");
    $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            if (date >= a && date <= b) {
                return true;
            }
            if(date >= x && date <= y) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

or, simplified :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var a = moment("2017-10-10");
    var b = moment("2017-10-15");
    var x = moment("2017-10-25");
    var y = moment("2017-10-30");
    $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            return (date >= a && date <= b) || (date >= x && date <= y);
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvLKGw)**

If you have many date ranges, you might write something like this :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            var dateRanges = [
                { 'start': moment('2017-10-10'), 'end': moment('2017-10-15') },
                { 'start': moment('2017-10-25'), 'end': moment('2017-10-30') },
                { 'start': moment('2017-11-10'), 'end': moment('2017-11-15') },
                { 'start': moment('2017-11-25'), 'end': moment('2017-11-30') },
                { 'start': moment('2017-12-10'), 'end': moment('2017-12-15') },
                { 'start': moment('2017-12-25'), 'end': moment('2017-12-30') },
                { 'start': moment('2018-01-10'), 'end': moment('2018-01-15') },
                { 'start': moment('2018-01-25'), 'end': moment('2018-01-30') },
                { 'start': moment('2018-02-10'), 'end': moment('2018-02-15') },
                { 'start': moment('2018-02-25'), 'end': moment('2018-02-30') }
            ];
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                return bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end);
            }, false);
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayxLeL)**

Comment: thanks.. its worked like a charm.. and i have question, how if using each?  according your code if i have 10 kinds of date that will be me disable,i must make 10 var ? please your suggestion.

Comment: For 10 date ranges you would need 20 dates. See additional example above for how you might approach that.

Comment: @ Roamer-1888... thanks brother.. very helped.. thanks so much for your suggestion..